# Git command to get live back to staging

Tags: git

Is there a git command to get live back to staging?

The reason for that is: every now and then we have images and stuff uploaded via the joomla admin on live and they don't get tracked by git so images get broken on staging...

so i'm wondering if there is a command we can do to pull those files from live back into git so i can load them back into staging.

my current setup:

local files on my working machine: those files get pushed to git repo.

staging server: staging.domain.com
I pull files from repo to this server for testing

Live server: domain.com
once all testing is done on staging, files get pulled from repo to live.

the problem is when images get uploaded straight into live server they don't get tracked by git so not in the repo.

What i need is to be able to do a git command that will pull those new files back in to the repo so i can pull them back to the staging server.

sorry about the bad explanation. I hope its understandable.

Cheers,
dan

Comment: "Live" and "staging" aren't in Git's vernacular.  Can you clarify if those are actual branch names and not environments?  Further, if you've got images making their way into the **source repository** outside of source control's knowledge, you should look to get that under wraps ASAP.

Comment: You're going to have to give us a lot more information about your setup. When you say "live" and "staging", are you talking about servers? Branches? These aren't standard Git terms.

Comment: It is still not clear. Please read again the comments by the others. To sum up: explain what "live" and "staging" are in your project.

Comment: i don't know how much clear i can be, LIVE = live server where the website is

STAGING = it's the staging server, where the testing website is, under a different sub URL.

those 2 servers pull files from Git REPO.

files on git REPO get updated from my local copy on my PC.

process is:
1. work on files on my PC. -> Commit -> push to repo
2. go to staging server and PULL files from repo for testing
3. once testing ok, go to live server and pull files from repo.

Comment: User-uploaded images are (probably) content, not code. Content generally shouldn't be committed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all i needed to do was login into the live server and do 
git add .
git commit
git push origin master

then login into staging and do a pull...